# How can I adjust classifier to the scale of the other

Tags: classification, data-transformation, scales, exploratory-data-analysis

I have 2 classifiers with different scales. How can I adjust one classifier to the scale of the other without loss of quality?

On the scatter plot we have [2 solutions plotted (x1, x2) against each other](http://i55.tinypic.com/2v0fm28.png). I believe using linear combination as a link function is not appropriate in this particular case.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please elaborate : do you want to scale x2 so it lies between 0 and 0.5 like x1, or do you want to be able to predict x1 from x2?

Comment: x1 and x2 are predictions from 2 different classifiers. I want to scale x2 so it lies between 0 and 0.5 like x1.

Comment: try squaring your x2. it will look more like x1, then.

Comment: Let me explain the problem in another way. After adjusting one solution to the scale of the other I want to fit linear regression so that intercept=0 and slope=1.

Comment: @Bob run a linear regression to get $x_1 = m x_2 + b$, then transform   as $\hat{x_2} \leftarrow m x_2 + b$. Then a linear regression of $\hat{x_2}$ vs $x_1$ will have intercept 0 and slope 1.

Comment: @shabbchef: You're right, but the relationship between $x_1$ and $x_2$ will still be curvilinear.  One needs to find *nonlinear* re-expressions of the variables before removing any "tilt" via linear regression.

Comment: (Sorry about misspelling your handle: it's the cleverest one around and so deserves to be typed correctly!)

Comment: @whuber the OP states he wants to 'scale x2' to get a linear fit with given slope and intercept. I live to serve.

Comment: @shabbychef: Ditto.  I think I got lucky this time in guessing the intent.  We have to recognize that non-statisticians often are unaware of the technical distinctions we make.  After all, a great deal of statistical consulting amounts to figuring out what someone might *really* be asking you!  Here the best clue is that the OP himself suggested a nonlinear re-expression ("link").  The scatterplot he posted helps immensely in understanding the situation, too.  The combination of those useful clues seemed sufficient to venture an answer rather than to keep probing for clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John Tukey described a simple method that works well in practice.  Pick three representative points within the scatterplot: one near each end and one in the middle.  Experiment with Box-Cox (power + log) transforms of either or both variables, *applying them only to the coordinates of the three representatives.*  (Tukey did this by hand; a spreadsheet speeds up the calculation.)  You want to make the slope between the left point and the middle point closely equal the slope between the middle and the right point.  Applying the resulting transformation(s) will linearize the plot.  (It basically has to: if you can get these points to line up, everything will line up.)

We can hope for homoscedasticity, too.  Your plot seems to exhibit a little more scatter on the right hand side.  This suggests choosing Box-Cox parameters (powers) less than 1.

For example, I can eyeball three points on your plot at (0.2, 0.05), (0.5, 0.2), and (0.7, 0.4).  Using just powers (which are Box-Cox transformations up to an affine change) I get slopes of 0.70 and 0.71 when leaving the x-coordinate unchanged but taking the 0.3 power of the y-coordinate.  The 0.3 power isn't much fun--one would prefer the 1/2 or maybe the 1/3 power--so I also tried taking the square root (1/2 power) of x and the logarithm (0 "power") of y.  The slopes are now 5.33 and 5.35: exactly equal within the imprecision of my coordinate estimates.

This suggests you should consider using $\left(\sqrt{x_1}, \log{x_2} \right)$ for your variables.  If this makes the scatter around the resulting linear scatterplot a little uneven (heteroscedastic), go back and try less severe powers, such as 1 and 1/3.  When you're done you can apply affine transformations (rescaling and recentering) to get the re-expressed variables in the range $[0, 1/2]$ if you really need that.

**Reference:**
Tukey, J, *EDA*.  Addison-Wesley (1977).